# How to emit a signal when serial port is connected or disconnected in Qt?

Tags: qt, serial-port

I used `QSerialPort` to communicate with a serial port. But how to emit a signal when it is changed(connected or disconnected)?

OS is win7. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with connected or disconnected? You can open or close a serial port, but that doesn't meant that is connected. Or you are using a USB-RS232?

Comment: Yes USB-RS232. 'connected' means plug the usb by hand but not open a serial port in source code.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773576/usb-device-detection-windows-linux-ft232r
Maybe you will need to add a entry for each USB-232 model. Another way is to check available ports periodicaly using `QSerialPortInfo`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a work-around for your problem (fixed mine at least).

I have a ComPort class that handles all my serial functionality of my GUI. When the user selected a COM-port, then a QTimer is started that checks the status periodically. When the timer is finished, the signal timeout() is emitted for which I wrote a custom slot:

```
// Custom slot to be called when timer times out.
void ComPort::checkComPortStatus()
{
    QSerialPortInfo *info = new QSerialPortInfo;
    QList<QSerialPortInfo> list = info->availablePorts();
    bool port_still_available = false;

    for (QSerialPortInfo &port : list) {
        if (port.portName() == serial_port->portName())
            port_still_available = true;
    }

    if (!port_still_available) {
        qDebug() << "Selected COM-port," << serial_port->portName() << ", no longer available!";

        delete serial_port;
        serial_port = nullptr;
        qDebug() << "COM-port is deleted.";

        delete timer;
        timer = new QTimer(this);
        qDebug() << "COM-port timer is deleted.";

        selectedPort_label->setText("Error: disconnected");
    }
}
```

This, ofcourse, is only useful when the port is still closed. When the port is opened, a standard signal is emited by QT (please consult the documentation):

```
errorOccurred(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)
```

I hope this helps!